# Update React Component after render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-sortable-listview to change order of list-item by drag and drop. Only drag item is again rendered so its position is updated but other have their previous position. When This component is re-rendered by other cause like some increment button, all position are being correct.
 So my question is when my react-native-sortable-list is rendered how can I re-render this again.
 Both ways to render by `forceUpdate()` and `this.setState()` , I could not follow as I can not update state in render function.
 What can be a possible way for doing this.

Comment: Hi, share some code. I guess you should be able to accomplish that using acombination of `renderRow` and `onChangeOrder`.

Comment: I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608834/update-position-of-all-places-in-react-native-sortable-listview) with code but no one have been interested so i have to post it in summarise form

Comment: Ok, but I cant help you if there is no code. Share a basic example at least

Comment: Sir, So I have send a link of same question but if you will say I will post the code here also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using componentWillMount or componentDidMount:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.setState({
    data: myData
  });
}
```

Basically at whatever stage your component is rendered you need to capture that event and call setState(); You could also re-render through a button as well. User clicks a button, then you setState(); Hope this helps!

Comment: This will not work, as will/didMount() only gets called once before/after the first rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that list but there should be some property like `onDrop` or something like that. You can pass a function to this event handler that might start sorting the list, you are passing in.

is it this list?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sortable-list

i would try what the `onReleaseRow` event handler does. Maybe something like:

```
<SortableList onReleaseRow{() => this.sortList() data={this.state.data}}/>

sortList() {
let sortedData = //sort data somehow
this.setState({
    data: sortedData})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `reRender` function down to your sortable list. ReactNativeList accepts a prop called onChangeOrder that is called each time row order is changed.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    reRender = () => {
      this.forceUpdate()
    }

    render() {
      return <ReactNativeList onChangeOrder={this.reRender} />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have find a way to re-render as follow.

```
  <SortableListView
      key={this.state.count}
      data={this.state.allObj}
      order={this.state.order}
      activeOpacity={0.5}
      onRowMoved={e => {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
        this.props.arrangedMilestoneList(e);
        console.log('onRowMoved is called');
      }}
      onMoveEnd={() => console.log('onMoveEnd is fired')}
      renderRow={(row, s1, i) => this.renderOneDraggableMilestone(row, s1, i)}
    />
```

What I am doing is I added a key attribute to `SortableListView` and update this key on each `onRowMoved` action. And because of this it causes re-render.